# Changing SwiftUI Popover Height

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to change the height of popover on SwiftUI on iPad? Setting the height of the frame inside popover view doesn't work.

My code is as shown:

```swift
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                // Enable popOver
            }) {
                Text("click me")
            }
        }.popover(isPresented: $showingPopOver, arrowEdge: .top) {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Change Picture")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showingPopOver.toggle()
                        self.imagePickerViewModel.isPresented.toggle()
                    }

                Text("Remove")
            }.frame(height: 200).background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not seem like it’s currently possible to change the frame of a popover.
I created bug report FB7465491, I suggest doing the same.